# replace characters in price calculation JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a script for percentage calculation on my e-commerce, but I have a problem.

If i use use characters such as: ", . %" the price value says "NaN".

So I made this:

```
 <input type="text" name="cost" onkeyup="disc()"> <br><br>

 <input type="text" name="discount" id="prized" onkeyup="updateInput()">   

 <input type="text" name="price" value="">

<script>

function updateInput(){
  var discount = document.getElementsByName("discount")[0].value;
  var cost = document.getElementsByName("cost")[0].value;
  document.getElementsByName("price")[0].value = cost - (cost * (discount / 100));
}


 function disc(){
  if($("#prized").val().length > 1) {
    var discount = document.getElementsByName("discount")[0].value;
    var cost = document.getElementsByName("cost")[0].value;
    document.getElementsByName("price")[0].value = cost - (cost * (discount / 100));
 }
}

</script>
```

How can I replace the characters when they are inserted on cost value or discount value?

I did some research, and I found an interesting function: `.replace`

I have no idea how to use it in my script.

Someone can help me reach my goal?

Comment: So what do you want to behaviour to be when you try to interpret a number after you encounter some `%` or `,` or `.`? How will you decide between which of `1,000.00` or `1.000,00` means `1000.00`? What if you have `55%10`?

Answer (score 0):

You should have to replace special characters **`,`** and **`&`** like this

```
var price = $(".price").val().replace(/,/g, "").replace("%", "")
```

This `replace(/,/g, "")` will replace multiple replace of comma `,`

Ex. 1,00,000 be 100000

Answer (score 0):

Why not validate your user input prior to calling your function? create a regex to only allow the characters you want. As it is your user can input any character they want in the input box. Probably a good idea to limit that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is the requirement, any way replace work like below,

```
var test = "90.56%";    
test = test.replace(/[.%]/g, "");
//test will be "9056"
```

Comment: I believe you mean `//test will be "9056"` _(String)_